# Copy the value from a property in an Ant propertyfile to another property

Tags: replace, ant, matching

I need to copy the value of one property in a propertyfile to a second property, and add that to the propertyfile.

For example, if I have a property file Test.properties containing

```
2018=jan;feb;mar    
2019=jan;feb;mar
2020=jan;feb;mar
********************************
name=john,math,sudha
```

my input property is "2020" and output is "2021", after running Ant Test.properties should contain

```
2018=jan;feb;mar    
2019=jan;feb;mar
2020=jan;feb;mar
2021=jan;feb;mar
********************************
name=john,math,sudha
```

with out changing the order How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
               <property name="prop.file" value="test.properties" />
               <property name="input" value="2020" />
               <property name="output" value="2021" />
                     <replaceregexp file="${prop.file}"
                           match="${input}(=)(.*)" 
                           replace="${input}=\2${line.separator}${output}=\2"
                           flags="gi"
                           byline="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use something based on the following:

The idea is to read the propertyfile, then use two [`<propertyset>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/propertyset.html) instances with the [`<echoproperties>` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html) to update the file.

```
<property name="prop.file" value="Test.properties" />

<property name="input" value="2020" />
<property name="output" value="2021" />

<property name="pf" value="prefix" />
<property name="input.prop" value="${pf}.${input}" />

<loadproperties srcfile="${prop.file}" prefix="${pf}" />

<echoproperties destfile="${prop.file}">
  <propertyset>
    <propertyref prefix="${pf}" />
    <mapper type="glob" from="${pf}.*" to="*" />
  </propertyset>

  <propertyset>
    <propertyref name="${input.prop}" />
    <mapper type="glob" from="${input.prop}*" to="${output}*" />
  </propertyset>
</echoproperties>
```

There's more code there than you might expect: the "prefix" is being used to ensure that the properties loaded from the file don't clash with any in your Ant buildfile as properties are imutable.

The order of the `propertysets` in the `echoproperties` task is important, especially if there is already a value for property "2021" in the file that you are updating.  Where properties appear in both sets, the value in the last propertyset seen "wins" and is echoed to the output file.